# User account creation safety and race condition concerns. Mongodb + nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

First question here :D

I am trying to deal with an edge case with user account creation using node.js and mongodb, where user or users attempt to create an account with the same username. When a new user attempts to create a new user account, I first check if it exists in the database using `findOne` which is an asynchronous call. Upon finishing finding one, there is a callback which calls another async call to a bcrypt subroutine.

I am scared of the following execution sequence:

`req->req->findOne->findOne ...`

or even:

`req->req->findOne->bcrypt->findOne ...`

How can I deal with such a situation?

Comment: You make a unique index on the collection on username, then no race condition should exist.

Comment: @Sammaye Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. Now when the second insert happens, it'll error out and I'll handle that.